# Telescope colimits

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two connected simplicial sets and 3 monomorphisms (injective) $a: X\rightarrow X$, $b: Y\rightarrow Y $ and $f: X\rightarrow Y$ such that

1. $f\circ a = b\circ f$
2. The pullback of $b:Y\rightarrow Y\leftarrow X:f $ is $X$ (unfortunately I don't know how to draw diagrams)

We suppose that the induced map by $f$ at the level of colimits  $colim(X\rightarrow^{a} X\rightarrow^{a} X \dots )\rightarrow colim (Y\rightarrow^{b} Y\rightarrow^{b} Y \dots )$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. I was wondering if $f$ has to be a weak homotopy equivalence (or homology equivalence)?

Comment: When you write that “the pullback of […] is $X$”, presumably you don’t just mean that the pullback has some arbitrary isomorphism to $X$, but rather that the specific commutative square $f \circ a = b \circ f$ is a pullback square?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Yes, exactly, I just do not know how to draw diagrams!

Comment: The [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) and [tikz-cd](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) packages are your friends!  Put the following into a *.tex file: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \begin{document} \begin{tikzcd} X \ar[r,"f"] \ar[d,"a"] & Y \ar[d,"b"] \\ X \ar[r,"f"] & Y \end{tikzcd} \end{document}` and then insert the resulting graphic into your question here (there’s a button in the MathOverflow editor toolbar for inserting images).

Comment: There's also [this graphical tool](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/) for generating tikz-cd code.